# Swift: My Google Maps View isn't showing up

Tags: ios, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to implement Google Maps SDK into my iOS app for the first time. After following Google's tutorial, Google Maps still does not show up in my view.

Here is my AppDelegate code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("\(myAPIKey)")
    return true
}
```

and here is the code in my View Controller, straight from Google:

```
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
        longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
    var mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
    mapsView = mapView

    var marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
    marker.title = "Sydney"
    marker.snippet = "Australia"
    marker.map = mapView
```

However, the view still doesn't show up. I checked my IBOutlet for my view - mapsView - and it is correct. Here is an image of my storyboard:[image]

Where the empty view outlined is my maps view. But here it what my app looks like when it runs: [image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the custom class of the view to a GMSMapView in the Storyboard instead of a UIView.

Comment: this detail is so simple and easy to forget